# Interrupção de uma requisição assíncrona

Tags: javascript, ajax

O que acontece quando o usuário, por exemplo, recarrega a página com uma requisição assíncrona em andamento? O servidor continua executando o script? E como posso interromper uma requisição em andamento via JS?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> O que acontece quando o usuário, por exemplo, recarrega a página com uma requisição assíncrona em andamento?

Depende do momento. Se a requisição já tiver sido enviada ao servidor, ela é processada normalmente (mas, é claro, a resposta nunca será entregue ao cliente). Se a requisição não tiver saído ainda, ele nunca chega ao servidor e não é processada. Em geral você vai cair no primeiro caso, não sei em que circunstâncias você conseguiria disparar uma requisição e recarregar a página antes mesmo de ela ser enviada.

> E como posso interromper uma requisição em andamento via JS?

Considerando que você esteja usando [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest), existe um método `abort`:

```
// Enviar:
var requisicao = new XMLHttpRequest();
requisicao.open("get", "arquivo.html", true);
requisicao.send();
// CANCELAR:
requisicao.abort();
```

Comment: Ótima resposta mas, me surgiu uma dúvida. Se a requisição for um post, por exemplo, e o servidor já tiver recebido, mesmo que dê o abort ela será processada normalmente certo?

Comment: @Caputo Acredito que sim (seja POST, GET ou qualquer outro verbo).

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Me surgiu esta dúvida / preocupação pois tenho uma requisição que leva cerca de 2 min. Neste caso é fácil para o usuário achar que deu erro na página e tentar recarregá-la.

Comment: Entendi @Oeslei. Mas você não tem uma indicação na tela de que tem algo demorado ocorrendo em background? Se não tiver, é sempre bom colocar.

Comment: Sim. Tem um loader no sistema para todas as requisições, e para as mais demoradas, como neste caso, tem um loader mais destacado também.