# Interromper requisição ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

Tenho um página onde é carregado um grid de eventos em ajax.
Também tenho nessa tela um menu de ações.

Assim que acesso, a página é carregada (inclusive o menu de ações), e o grid de eventos, por ser mais pesado fica carregando separadamente.

O que está acontecendo é que enquanto a tabela de eventos não carrega completamente, não consigo acionar uma ação.

Exemplo:
Entro na página e o grid de eventos começa carregar (vejo no console a requisição pendente)
Quando clico em qualquer link, a requisição é feita, mas só concluída depois que o grid de eventos termina de carregar.
Neste momento, duas requisições pendentes estão no console apenas: a do grid de eventos, e a do link que cliquei.

Alguém tem uma luz aí de como resolver este problema?

Todas requisições são assíncronas.
Penso em abortar as requisições pendentes quando se clica em uma ação, mas como??

Comment: Isto responderia à sua dúvida? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/22589/interrup%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-uma-requisi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-ass%C3%ADncrona

Answer (score 5):

Quando usas o método [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) do jQuery ele retorna um objeto que podes guardar numa variável. Assim:

```
var ajax = $.ajax(...);
```

esse objeto tem métodos próprios e um deles é o `.abort()`, portanto é só usar `ajax.abort();` para cancelar o pedido.

Podes solucionar o problema também com o design do próprio código. Ou seja planear no código para atender a este problema. Mas para ajudar aí preciso de ver como tens o código agora. De qq maneira uma solução é a que sugeri em cima e o que tu próprio já procuras: cancelar o pedido ajax.

Comment: Pesquisei sobre o .abort(), mas em que momento eu chamaria ele??3

Comment: @Gabriel pode chamar quando ele está à espera da resposta. No caso do código/flow que descreveu pode chamar quando clica num novo link.

Comment: Fiz o que vc propôs Sérgio. O que está acontecendo é que a requisição é abortada ao clicar em um link, mas o tempo que está levando para carregar a pagina do link está sendo a mesma que levava enquanto esperava o término da requisição do grid de eventos. Ou seja, é como se a requisição apenas mudasse o status para 'cancelado', mas a próxima requisição ainda esperasse esta que está cancelada 'terminar'.

Comment: @Gabriel podes colocar o código que tens na pergunta? assim dá para ver se o problema está aí ou no lado do servidor.

Comment: Infelizmente não Sérgio. Um teste que fiz: na função php chamada pelo ajax, coloquei um sleep(20) e limpei meu sucess do ajax. O que ocorre é que mesmo cancelando a requisição, o link clicado só é aberto (mesmo em outra aba), depois deste tempo estipulado..

Comment: @Gabriel sem ver o seu jQuery é dificil ajudar mais... não consegue colocar parte para eu perceber como está a correr esse código?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer de modo recursivo, ele só carrega o próximo ao final do atual, assim fica possível entrar uma solicitação no meio e ela abortar o restante, carregando o que deseja sem esperar toda a grade ser carregada.

Como estou com o mesmo problema a solução foi a seguinte

```
var arrTabela;//contem um array de id's para a consulta de cada linha da grade
var tot = 4; //pegar o total de linhas da tabelas 

function teste(arrTabela) {
    if(arrTabela < 0) return;
    return $.ajax({
        url : 'minha url q retorna o total',
        data: {id : arrTabela[0]},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            //subistitui o valor desejado
            $("#tot-list"+id).html(data);
            //remove o item usado no array
            arrTabela.splice(1,1);
            tot--;
            //chama novamente a função
            teste();
        }
    });
};
```

Não foi exatamente deste jeito, mas a ideia é essa, desculpa os erros de sintaxe que devem ter muitos, mas fiz de cabeça este aqui. Espero que ajude!

Comment: tinha esquecido do principal que é chamar a função novamente ao termino da mesma mas ja esta ok :)